# pandasで日付時刻、数値のcsvファイルを読み込んでグラフ化したい

Tags: python, python3, pandas

プログラミング初心者です。お見苦しく申し訳ありません。
日付時刻、数値だけのcsvファイルを読み込んで、グラフ化したいだけなのですが、多くのサイトを回って参考にしてもエラーが無くなりません。
ずばり、修正案をいただけないでしょうか。

1)読み込むcsvファイル

```
time,count
2019/09/13 10:00:00,5123
2019/09/13 10:00:01,4872
2019/09/13 10:00:02,3488
〜以下略〜
```

2)作りかけのコード

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

dtypes = {'time': 'str', 'count': 'int'}
parse_dates = ['time']
data = pd.read_csv("tmp.csv", index_col=0, dtype=dtypes, parse_dates=parse_dates)

df_tmp = data.iloc[:, [0,1]]
df_tmp.plot()
plt.savefig("Graph03.png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: どんなエラーが出ているのかもコピー＆ペーストしていただけると回答しやすいです。「編集」から追記できますのでお試しくださいませ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

単純に、この段階では`df_tmp`を作る処理が余計で、`data`をそのまま`plot`すれば良いでしょう。
縦軸の範囲をどうするとか複数データを重ねるとかは、まあ必要になってから後でやりましょう。

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

dtypes = {'time': 'str', 'count': 'int'}
parse_dates = ['time']
data = pd.read_csv("tmp.csv", index_col=0, dtype=dtypes, parse_dates=parse_dates)

data.plot()
plt.savefig("Graph03.png")
plt.show()
```

結果はこうなります。
[image: result_figure]